# Pulsar send() method has low data write efficiency

Tags: python, queue, apache-pulsar

When I use a Python program to write data to Pulsar, the QPS of a single partition can only reach around 500.
I need to ensure that data is sent successfully and in order, I use the `send()` method of a single producer

SO. Is it normal for the QPS of the `send()` method to be around 500 in the case of a single partition and a single producer?

test code:

```
from pulsar import Client
import time

service_url=''
topic = ''

data = '0xf9ba0955b0509ac6138908ccc50fasdfa5bd296e48d7d,0x74b1d2f771adsfasdfasebdbea80fe4013bdace4fc4b653322c2895c'
client = Client(service_url)
producer = client.create_producer(topic)

for i in range(18000,18100):
    start_time = time.time()
    for j in range(0,10000):
        producer.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Block {i} takes {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds to write")
```

I tried using the `send_async()` method to send data, which is much faster, but it cannot guarantee that the data is completely successful. I need to immediately stop sending subsequent data after a data sending failure to ensure the order of the data.

I can achieve fast performance when using `ack=-1` in Kafka as well.

Comment: I've tried pulsar-client-dotnet speed today and it gives 100K per second on local cluster

Comment: The `send()` method you are using is a synchronous, blocking call. It waits for the messages to get persisted inside Pulsar as indicated by at least `ackQuorum` number of acks from the different storage nodes. Setting `ack=-1` for Kafka just means that you don't wait for the acks which would speed up the publish rate, but might result in data loss.